# find and replace number as text not working in vba

Tags: vba

I have a sheet of data and in column D they are numbers (e.g. 15, 16). For data analysis purposes, I need to replace them as text so they can be displayed as 015, 016 specifically. And for the rest of numbers I can leave them as text but not add the leading zero.

My current codes only change them into text but failed to add the leading zero that I need it. And again since I only need 15 to be 015 and 16 to be 016, that's how I set up my codes. The rest can be as text without the leading zeros.

```
Sub test()
With Worksheets("RTLDC")
    Dim LR99 As Long, xy As Long, ij As Long
    Dim fndList As Variant, rplcList As Variant
    LR99 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    fndList = Array("15", "16")
    rplcList = Array("015", "016")
    Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"
    For xy = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        For ij = 1 To LR99
            If Range("D" & ij).Value = fndList(xy) Then
                Range("D" & ij).Value = rplcList(xy)
            End If
        Next ij
    Next xy
End With
End Sub
```

First picture is what I see after I ran my vba and second is my desire results.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a cell format issue. I think that it should be text instead number

Comment: did you tried `Range("D" & ij).NumberFormat = "@"`?

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm!! Appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a format range issue,  try formatting by cell

`Range("D" & ij).NumberFormat = "@"`

Could be better if you use

`Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"`

Reference https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/entire-rows-columns.html

Comment: Or shorter: `[B:B].NumberFormat = "@"`